# How to keep tract of minted NFTs?

Tags: nft, erc-721, oracles

I have a simple ERC721 NFT smart contract. I need to do something if the owner of any of my minted NFT changes. How can I trigger an action in my smart contract if the owner of my NFT changes?

I guess this can be done via oracles. I can (somehow) keep track of NFT owners off-chain (like Etherscan) and send that information to my contract (or to oracle contract). Is there any other way to do this? (I am asking this because there is a function named `ownerOf` which returns the owner address of the given token ID)

Answer (score 0):

In solidity you can just subbscribe to events for a specific smart contract so you can emit an event from nft contract and listen for events in your server(node) and trigger some other function calls .
example would bee something like this :

```
const instance = Web3.eth.contract(ABI).at(ADDRESS); instance.FooEvent().watch((err, response) => { 
 console.log (response); 
})
```

In response you will have all events emited from `fooEvent()`.